# How do I match contents of an element in XPath (lxml)?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, predicate

I want to parse HTML with lxml using XPath expressions. My problem is matching for the contents of a tag:

For example given the

```
<a href="http://something">Example</a>
```

element I can match the href attribute using

```
.//a[@href='http://something']
```

but the given the expression

```
.//a[.='Example']
```

or even

```
.//a[contains(.,'Example')]
```

lxml throws the 'invalid node predicate' exception.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Example code:

```
from lxml import etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

html = '<a href="http://something">Example</a>'
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser)

print tree.find(".//a[text()='Example']").tag
```

Expected output is 'a'. I get 'SyntaxError: invalid node predicate'

Comment: Instead of using StringIO, you could have used etree.fromstring() to parse your html.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would try with:

`.//a[text()='Example']`

using xpath() method:

```
tree.xpath(".//a[text()='Example']")[0].tag
```

If case you would like to use iterfind(), findall(), find(), findtext(), keep in mind that advanced features like **value comparison and functions** are not available in [ElementPath](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm).

> **lxml.etree** supports the simple path
>   syntax of the find, findall and
>   findtext methods on ElementTree and
>   Element, as known from the original
>   ElementTree library (ElementPath). As
>   an lxml specific extension, these
>   classes also provide an xpath() method
>   that supports expressions in the
>   complete XPath syntax, as well as
>   custom extension functions.

Comment: I don't want to find the link based on href, but based on the text it contains: "Example" in the above example :)

.//a[@href='http://something'] works the way it is...

Comment: you need to remove an =
.//a[text()='Example']

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this one raises "SyntaxError: invalid node predicate" too

Comment: Thank you: with XPath() it really works. Strangely enough @href works in both cases.

Comment: @systempuntoout Then is `.//a[text()='Example']`  invalid in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer has performance drawbacks. Consider using:

```
xml_doc.finditer('.//element[.="text to match"]')
```

instead.

This is documented in the find syntax docs here for the original xml.ElementTree implementation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax
and lxml.etree says it uses the same restricted syntax for its find methods.