# python ElementTree find child with certain text value

Tags: python, elementtree

I've been searching for a while. Is there a way to directly retrieve a child based on the text value of a tag?

For example:

```
 <a>
   <b>
       <c>h</c>
   </b>
   <b>
       <c>j</c>
   </b>
</a>
```

And say I want to retrieve the child be whose "c" text value == j. Is there a way of doing this other than having to get all the "b" children and looping through them and checking the c value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) you can use the XPath expression `//c[text()='j']`

```
import lxml.etree as et

doc = '''
<a>
   <b>
       <c>h</c>
   </b>
   <b>
       <c>j</c>
   </b>
</a>
'''

tree = et.fromstring(doc)

tree.xpath("/a/b/c[text()='j']")
```

This answer is relevant: [How do I match contents of an element in XPath (lxml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637760/how-do-i-match-contents-of-an-element-in-xpath-lxml/2637909#2637909)