# Python XPath SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Tags: python, xml, xpath

i am trying to parse an xml like

```
<document>
    <pages>

    <page>   
       <paragraph>XBV</paragraph>

       <paragraph>GHF</paragraph>
    </page>

    <page>
       <paragraph>ash</paragraph>

       <paragraph>lplp</paragraph>
    </page>

    </pages>
</document>
```

and here is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("../../xml/test.xml")

root = tree.getroot()

path="./pages/page/paragraph[text()='GHF']"

print root.findall(path)
```

but i get an error

```
print root.findall(path)
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 390, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path, namespaces)
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 293, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 224, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

what is wrong with my xpath?

**Follow up**

Thanks falsetru, your solution worked. I have a follow up. Now, i want to get all the paragraph elements that come before the paragraph with text `GHF`. So in this case i only need the `XBV` element. I want to ignore the `ash` and `lplp`. i guess one way to do this would be

```
result = []
for para in root.findall('./pages/page/'):
    t = para.text.encode("utf-8", "ignore")
    if t == "GHF":
       break
    else:
        result.append(para)
```

but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[ElementTree's XPath support is limited.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) Use other library like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.etree
root = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')

path = "./pages/page/paragraph[text()='GHF']"
print(root.xpath(path))
```

Comment: thanks man! can i also do something like text.contains("something") and text.notContains("something")?

Comment: @AbtPst, You can: `path="./pages/page/paragraph[contains(text(),'something')]"
` / `path="./pages/page/paragraph[not(contains(text(),'something'))]"`

Comment: No you can not for `find_all` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637760/how-do-i-match-contents-of-an-element-in-xpath-lxml  since `def prepare_predicate(next, token)` fails

Comment: thanks man! that worked. it gives me all the elements i need. just a followup. now what if i want all the paragraphs before i see the 'GHF' paragraph? Once i see the paragraph with the text 'GHF', i want to ignore everything else that comes after it. can i do that?

Comment: @AbtPst, Sorry, I don't get it. Please post another question.

Comment: thanks, i have updated the question. please take a look

Comment: @AbtPst, Please post a separated question instead of updating the current question.

Answer (score 6):

As @falsetru mentioned, `ElementTree` doesn't support `text()` predicate, but it supports matching child element by text, so in this example, it is possible to search for a `page` that has a `paragraph` with specific text, using the path `./pages/page[paragraph='GHF']`. The problem here is that there are multiple `paragraph` tags in a `page`, so one would have to iterate for the specific `paragraph`. In my case, I needed to find the `version` of a `dependency` in a maven pom.xml, and there is only a single `version` child so the following worked:

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2] ns = {"pom": "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"}

In [3] print ET.parse("pom.xml").findall(".//pom:dependencies/pom:dependency[pom:artifactId='some-artifact-with-hardcoded-version']/pom:version", ns)[0].text
Out[1]: '1.2.3'
```