# xpath - select parent where child has a specific attrib value with namespace dictionary

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I need the node `AX_Namensnummer` where child node `istBestandteilVon` has the attribute value `urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX`.

And i want to use a namespace dictionary.

Im working in Dynamo with `Python 2.7` and `ElementTree`. So i can't use `lxml`!

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AX_Bestandsdatenauszug
    xmlns="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
    xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfs"
    xmlns:wfsext="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfsext"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/ogc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 NAS-Operationen.xsd">

    <enthaelt>
    <gml:featureMember>
                <AX_Namensnummer gml:id="DEBBAL0600000XUm">
                    <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://www.adv-online.de/">urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600000XUm</gml:identifier>
                    <istBestandteilVon xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600000XOX"/>
                    <benennt xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600000Y09"/>
                </AX_Namensnummer>
                <AX_Namensnummer gml:id="DEBBAL0600001XUm">
                    <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://www.adv-online.de/">urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XUm</gml:identifier>
                    <istBestandteilVon xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX"/>
                    <benennt xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600000Y08"/>
                </AX_Namensnummer>
            </gml:featureMember>
    </enthaelt>
</AX_Bestandsdatenauszug>
```

code:

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variables.

path="file.xml"
uniStr = unicode(open(path, 'r').read())
fixed = uniStr.encode('ascii', 'replace')
fixed.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(fixed))
root = tree.getroot()

xpath=".//adv:AX_Namensnummer[adv:istBestandteilVon/@xlink:href='urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX']"

ns = {"":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0", "adv":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0","gco":"http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco", 
"gmd":"http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd","gml":"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2","ows":"http://www.opengis.net/ows",
"wfs":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfs","wfsext":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfsext","xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
"xlink":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","ogc":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/ogc"}

elem = root.find(xpath,ns)

print elem
```

**xpath:**

.//adv:AX_Namensnummer[adv:istBestandteilVon/@xlink:href='urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX']

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Any ideas whats wrong? Can Python 2.7 and ElementTree handle this kind of xpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python XPath SyntaxError: invalid predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830821/python-xpath-syntaxerror-invalid-predicate)

Comment: Can't use the lib lxml @ Andersson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath, including the predicate, looks good. It must be a [limitation of ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

Maybe try targeting the `adv:istBestandteilVon` with a basic predicate and then getting its parent (`..` is the [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) of `parent::*`)...

```
xpath=".//adv:istBestandteilVon[@xlink:href='urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX']/.."
```

**EDIT**

To only return `adv:AX_Namensnummer`...

```
xpath=".//adv:AX_Namensnummer/adv:istBestandteilVon[@xlink:href='urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX']/.."
```

Comment: Your Xpath in realy a option, but i got a realy big xml. This section was only a example. When i use your xpath. I got two or more parents, because there are more than on `adv:istBestandteilVon` with the same value in my xml. So can i ask for e specific parent name? like `xpath=".//adv:istBestandteilVon[@xlink:href='urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0600001XOX']/..adv:AX_Namensnummer"`? This example don't work...

Comment: @Yuli - `parent::` and `self::` axes don't seem to work in ElementTree, so you'll have to add `adv:AX_Namensnummer` back to the beginning of the XPath. I updated my answer with an example. If that doesn't work, please consider updating your example XML so we can reproduce.