# XML - How to find specific attributes

Tags: xml

I'm looking to print ALL elements witch have these three specific attributes: 'name', 'top', 'left' from an XML file.
So far i can do it manualy by firstly printing all tags:

`for elm in root.findall("./"): print(elm.tag)`

and then i can go throgh what it prints one by one for example like:

`for elm in root.findall("./momentaryButton"): print(elm.attrib['name'],elm.attrib['top'],elm.attrib['left'])` 
etc.

I have a problem in writing a program which will find all the lines containing the XML tag properties "name", "top" and "left" and will write value of this properties in console all at once. Is there a way to do it?

I'm pasting an XML file below:

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like

```
for elm in root.findall(".//*"): 
    if 'left' and 'name' and 'top' in elm.attrib.keys():
        for k,v in  elm.attrib.items():
            print(k,":",v)
        print('------------')
```

The output should all the attributes and their values for those elements which have all the three specified attributes.

Comment: Thanks again, I guess in my last post I missunderstood You, I was trying to make a program which will find all the lines containing xml tag properties "name", "top" and "left" and will write value of this properties in console, e.g:
MomentaryPushButton1 50 10
(Program is printing only those 3 values - name, top and left) in every element that has those attributes

Answer (score 0):

An XPath to select the elements that have the attribute `@name`, or `@top`, or `@left`:

```
//*[@name or @top or @left]
```

Applied to your code:

```
for elm in root.findall("//*[@name or @top or @left]"): 
print(elm.attrib['name'], elm.attrib['top'], elm.attrib['left'])
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\mixha\OneDrive\Desktop\task_Obiedzinski\task_1_Obiedzinski.py", line 12, in <module>
   from pathlib import Path
  File "C:\Users\mixha\miniconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 395, in findall
   return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "C:\Users\mixha\miniconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 368, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "C:\Users\mixha\miniconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 321, in prepare_predicate
raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Comment: This is an error that occured

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the `or` criteria. Apparently, the XPath support is limited  https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support others have reported issues, and found lxml to work for them https://stackoverflow.com/a/33830958/14419