# Invalid Predicate using xml etree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml.etree

iclasses = self.xml.getroot().find(".//iclass[((docvars/docvar[@key='isa' and @value='A32']) or (docvars/docvar[@key='isa' and @value='T32']))]")

File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 233, in prepare_predicate
raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
make: *** [graphics] Error 1

Trying to fetch all iclasses where docvars/docvar[@key ='isa' and @value='A32']

Don't know what wrong i am doing

Comment: Is the XPath you are showing hard-coded or do you construct it somehow?

Comment: Does this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33830958/3710053

Comment: i tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/33830958/3710053 this thing already but it didn't solve problem and yes this lxml module i have in my list is not working well with python3 so tried using xml etree instead of lxml xpath

Comment: I would add python as a tag, to get more help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems nothing wrong with your XPath, but would simplify it to this:

```
.//iclass[docvars/docvar[@key='isa'][@value[.='A32' or .='T32']]]
```

Comment: even simplifying it didn't solve the cause, anyway thanks siebe

Comment: hey @siebe any idea , how to write equivalent of this     decodenodes = self.xml.getroot().xpath("//encodingindex[@instructionset='A32' or @instructionset='T32']//hierarchy | //encodingindex[@instructionset='A32' or @instructionset='T32']//node[@groupname] | //encodingindex[@instructionset='A32' or @instructionset='T32']//iclass_sect")  using xml.etree find method

Comment: I would first use "//encodingindex[@instructionset[.='A32' or .='T32']]" and with that result select ".//hierarchy|.//node[@groupname]|.//iclass_sect" > But take care in using double slahes with large xml-sets it will become slow. Better is to use a more explicit path